# Aligning equals signs across Beamer blocks

Tags: beamer, equations, align

I've got a Beamer frame consisting of two blocks that contain some equations:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Modell}
  \begin{block}{A  $(X_{t})$}
    \begin{align*}
    X_{t} = \epsilon_{t} \quad \text{mit} \quad \epsilon_{t}
    \overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma_{X}^{2}\right)
    \end{align*}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{B $(Y_{t})$}
    \begin{align*}
      Y_{t} &= \sigma_{Y,t}\: \eta_{t}, \\ \sigma_{Y,t}^{2} &= \omega + \alpha_{Y} Y_{t-1}^{2} + \beta_{Y}\sigma_{Y,t-1}^{2} \quad \text{mit} \quad  \sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}}\cdot \eta_{t} \overset{iid}{\sim} t\left(\nu\right). 
    \end{align*}
  \end{block}

\end{frame}
```

I would like like for *all* equals signs to be aligned, in other words I would like alignment across my two blocks. Normally I would use `intertext` but since I'm dealing with two block environments I don't think that would work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is one possibility. Use of phantom to repeat the longest equation of block 2 in block 1.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Modell}
  \begin{block}{A  $(X_{t})$}
    \begin{align*}
    X_{t} &= \epsilon_{t} \quad \text{mit} \quad \epsilon_{t}
    \overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma_{X}^{2}\right)\\
\phantom{\sigma_{Y,t}^{2}} &\phantom{= \omega + \alpha_{Y} Y_{t-1}^{2} + \beta_{Y}\sigma_{Y,t-1}^{2} \quad \text{mit} \quad  \sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}}\cdot \eta_{t} \overset{iid}{\sim} t\left(\nu\right).} 
    \end{align*}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{B $(Y_{t})$}
    \begin{align*}
      Y_{t} &= \sigma_{Y,t}\: \eta_{t}, \\ \sigma_{Y,t}^{2} &= \omega + \alpha_{Y} Y_{t-1}^{2} + \beta_{Y}\sigma_{Y,t-1}^{2} \quad \text{mit} \quad  \sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}}\cdot \eta_{t} \overset{iid}{\sim} t\left(\nu\right). 
    \end{align*}
  \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good but is there a way of getting rid of that extra whitespace after the first equation in block A?

Comment: You can strategically allocate \vspace{xxcm} to reduce the white space. For your question, I just tried \vspace{-1cm} inserted between the two blocks and the result is promising.

Comment: @user2249626 what about `\documentclass[t]{beamer}`?

Comment: @user2249626 There is surely a skip that `align` uses; it would be best to `\vspace{-\thatskipthatalignuses}`, whatver that skip is.

Answer (score 1):

Whit a dynamic placement and whitout `\hphantom` :

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,array}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newlength{\myl}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\rule{0pt}{1.4em}\hfill$}m{\myl}<{$}}

\newenvironment{MyAlign}{%
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.5pt}%

    \smallskip

    $\begin{array}{Zcl}
    }{%
    \end{array}$

    \smallskip

    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setlength{\myl}{1cm}

  \frametitle{Modell}
  \begin{block}{A  $(X_{t})$}
    \begin{MyAlign}
    X_{t} &=& \epsilon_{t} \quad \text{mit} \quad \epsilon_{t}
    \overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma_{X}^{2}\right)\\
    \end{MyAlign}
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{B $(Y_{t})$}
    \begin{MyAlign}
      Y_{t} &=& \sigma_{Y,t}\: \eta_{t}, \\
      \sigma_{Y,t}^{2} &=& \omega + \alpha_{Y} Y_{t-1}^{2} + \beta_{Y}\sigma_{Y,t-1}^{2} \quad \text{mit} \quad  \sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}}\cdot \eta_{t} \overset{iid}{\sim} t\left(\nu\right).\\
    \end{MyAlign}
  \end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```